# Help in solving the geometry question

Tags: geometry, contest-math

I having the following question with me which is a part of the 2013 IMO shortlist

"Let $ABC$ be an acute-angled triangle with orthocenter $H$, and let $W$ be a point on
side $BC$. Denote by $M$ and $N$ the feet of the altitudes from $B$ and $C$, respectively. Denote
by $\omega_1$ the circumcircle of $BW N$. Analogously, denote by $\omega_2$ the circumcircle of $CWM$.Let $P$ be the point on $\omega_1$ such that $W P$ is parallel to $CN$, and let $Q$ be the point on $\omega_2$ such
that $W Q$ is parallel to $BM$. Prove that $P$, $Q$ and $H$ are collinear if and only if $BW = CW$
or $AW$ is perpendicular to  $BC$."

I tried a lot but failed in coming up with a nice synthetic solution. Could anyone please help me out with it

Comment: "I tried a lot". What have you tried so far?

Comment: And the condition $BW\parallel CW$ makes no sense. Do you mean $BW=CW$?

Comment: @Dr.Mathva you are right I am sorry... I have edited the question

Comment: @saisanjeev: You say that you "failed in coming up with a nice synthetic solution". Did you find a *not-so-nice* synthetic solution? a coordinate one? Can you convey anything about where your attempt(s) fell apart? The more you tell of what you tried ---even when you failed--- the better we can help: we won't waste time duplicating your effort, and we might be able to identify an error or indicate alternative steps. (That the source related this problem to another, but that you couldn't see the connection, would've been nice to know *before* DrMathva spent time writing up a lengthy answer.)

Answer (score 0):

*Too long for a comment (and it has several pictures)*

Now I know why this problem sounds so familiar to me. This was the original proposal of the first geometry Problem from the [IMO shortlist 2013](https://www.imo-official.org/problems/IMO2013SL.pdf)! The solution to the modified problem might be helpful.

Nevertheless, the problem selected by the committee for the IMO (see $4^{th}$ problem of IMO $2013$) was apparently "more suitable for the competition":

> **Problem 4, IMO 2013**
>
> > Let $\triangle ABC$ be an acute-angled triangle with orthocenter $H$, and let $W$ be a point on side $BC$. Denote by $M$ and $N$ the feet of the altitudes from $B$ and $C$, respectively. Denote by $\omega{1}$ the circumcircle of $BWN$, and let $X$ be the point on $\omega_1$ which is diametrically opposite to $W$. Analogously, denote by $\omega_2$ the circumcircle of $CWM$, and let $Y$ be the point on $\omega_2$ which is diametrically opposite to $W$. Prove that $X, Y$ and $H$ are collinear.

---

You can find the official solution in the *pdf* I linked above and alternative solutions [here](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/2013_IMO_Problems/Problem_4)

---

I personally think that the best solution is provided by Evan Chen in his excellent [*Euclidean Geometry in Mathematical Olympiads*](http://web.evanchen.cc/geombook.html).

But first the hints:

$15$. Do you see a pair of perpendicular lines

$106$. Add a Miquel point

$157$. Show that $X, H, P$ are collinear, where $P$ is said Miquel point.

Finally

> [image] [image]
> [image]

Finally, I've made a picture of your problem in Geogebra that might help other users to figure out how to solve it

[image]

Comment: yeah I did see that question as a comment in the shortlist. However I fail in noticing the connection between the originally proposed problem, which is this one and the problem which was finally given....